# installing skimage with pip3 fails

Tags: python, pip, scikit-image

I am trying to pip install the package "skimage" on my Ubuntu VM to analyze structural similarity of images with scikit-image. But I always get a strange error. I already tried to install it with conda but it didn't succeeded either. Conda seems to know just "scikit-image" but not "skimage". The required packages like numpy, matplotlib, ... are installed and upgraded already.

My input:

```
pip3 install skimage
```

the error:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-k9rh2ebf/skimage/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-k9rh2ebf/skimage/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-k9rh2ebf/skimage/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-k9rh2ebf/skimage/
    Complete output (3 lines):
    
    *** Please install the `scikit-image` package (instead of `skimage`) ***
    
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try `pip3 install scikit-image`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally after a lot of trying I figured out it had to do with my virtual machine I was using. In the prebuilt Ubuntu image for VirtualBox I downloaded, something seems to be wrong with the installation paths.
Setting up a native Ubuntu (without VM) solved the problem for me. The skimage library is empty and only points to the sicikit-image library and is normally installed with the installation of scikit-image (which didn't work because of the VM).
Now on my native ubuntu everything works as it should.

Comment: The problem is you used the wrong name for the package, it's literally in the error log you posted. Maybe you had some other issues with your VM, but that's not relevant to nearly any other user online, and you would still need to use the right package name.

Answer (score 2):

Look in to the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-image/) In order to install it you need to use the following command

```
pip install scikit-image
```

if you want to install it using the word skimage

```
sudo apt-get install python-skimage
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in the example code on the scikit-image website they always use `from skimage import structural_similarity as ssim`. If I try to run this code I get the error `ImportError: No module named skimage`.
If I replace skimage with scikit-image for the import command I get this error: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` (with an arrow pointing on the "-" between scikit an image).

Comment: It's seems like an different issue, in order to test it try this. Open the terminal you used to install the package, then type "python" to open an interactive session then try type "from skimage import structural_similarity as ssim" and enter and check if you still get the same error.

Comment: For me sudo apt-get install python3-skimage worked instead of python so might depend on the version as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can install it using
`pip install -U scikit-image` or this `pip install scikit-image`